# Jquery when with multiple promise

Tags: jquery, promise

I am sending multiple promise to get user details using ajax.

```
var a= APP.request('user:getID');//Promise request
var b= APP.request('user:getName');//Promise request
var c= APP.request('user:getNumber');//Promise request
var d= APP.request('user:getAge');//Promise request
$.when(a.done(), b.done(), c.done(), d.done()).done(function() {
    console.log("Saving to single view.");//Working fine when ajax url is up.not working if any one url goes down.
}
```

This will work if all the url's are up.
But if any one url is down it will not enter inside when block.

I just modified the code and introduced **then**, still same problem.

```
$.when(a.then(), b.then(), c.then(), d.then()).then(function() {
    console.log("Saving to single view.");
}
```

I am not able to get what's wrong with my code.

**Update**: i have to execute $when block only after all the promises are being executed.

Comment: if any of the items fail then what do you want to do

Comment: i have to execute block which is inside $when. It should happen only after all the promises are being executed.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mjeqq8q/2/

Comment: what is teh expected parameters to the done callback

Comment: @ArunPJohny i need to execute $when after all promise got executed. because i need to get return values from each promise.

Comment: do you want to return values from failed one's also....

Comment: @ArunPJohny regardless of return i need to execute $when block only after all promises executed. if promise returns value i will use it or i will just proceed with $when block. but executing all promise is mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success with using an array of promises

```
var finalCheck = [];
```

then `.push()`

```
finalCheck.push( APP.request('user:getID') ) ;  //Promise request
finalCheck.push( APP.request('user:getName'));  //Promise request
finalCheck.push( APP.request('user:getNumber'));//Promise request
finalCheck.push( APP.request('user:getAge'));   //Promise request
```

you may or may not benefit from moving some logic into a `Defferred` function.  I like this because I have to do that work after recovery/fallback from a failed subrequest, and this makes that method available from multiple places.  The important part here is that the `Defferred` function comes before the `$.when.apply()`.

```
var AfterAllRequests = $.Deferred().done(function () {
             // real final work here...
             console.log("Saving to single view.");
        });
```

and wait for success or failure of those promises

```
$.when.apply($, finalCheck).done(function () {
            AfterAllRequests.resolve();
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log(" Some GET(s) failed, handle fallback content ...");
            // ....
            AfterAllRequests.resolve();
        });
```

**Untested variant** - You could try `.always()` instead of `.done()` and `.fail()` but I (um) always have different things to do depending on success or failure of the group of promises.  It would look something like:

```
$.when.apply($, finalCheck).always(function () {
           // well now it is time....and you may not need a deferred anymore
            AfterAllRequests.resolve();
        });
```

Comment: i need to execute one function after all promise executed regardless of fail/pass, make sure i need to execute my method **after all promise execution(done/fail)**

Comment: That is the point of `AfterAllRequests.resolve()` - you can do it in `done` and/or `fail` logic.  I updated the answer to make this a little clearer.

Comment: let me try it.
But adding same code in success and fail makes no sense right? :-)

Comment: `$.when(a.then(), b.then(), c.then(), d.then()).then(function() {
    myFunction();
}, function(result) {myFunction();});` will even work right? but still it is repeating my function

Comment: The common code is refactored into the `defferred` function - so the only repeated code is the `AfterAllRequests.resolve()` that fires the `defferred` function.   You could try `.always()` - I'll update the answer

Comment: Notice that `AfterAllRequests` is fulfilled *as soon as the first* of your request fails, not after all of the promises have settled. If you really were looking for that, then you'd just had to replace `done` with `always` in your original code.